# React Native FlatList inside ScrollView issue

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have the following issue, FlatList is rendered inside ScrollView, and everything seems to fine except that while FlatList scrolling the buttons in ScrollView are not responding.

Structure is something like this:

ScrollView - vertical
Button
ListView - horizontal
ScrollView

Comment: got same problem, I heard put FlatList inside ScrollView affect performance(make it worse) but can't find more useful info

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098599/flatlist-inside-scrollview-doesnt-scroll.........see here

Answer (score 0):

use [nestedscrollenabled](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled) prop for the children

```
<FlatList nestedScrollEnabled />
```