# FlatList inside ScrollView doesn't scroll

Tags: react-native

I've 4 `FlatList`s with `maxHeight` set to `200` inside a `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView>
  <FlatList/>
  <FlatList/>
  <FlatList/>
  <FlatList/>
</ScrollView>
```

and when I try to scroll a `FlatList`, it doesn't scroll but the `ScrollView` scrolls. How do I fix this issue ?

**Full Source Code**

```
import { Component, default as React } from 'react';
import { FlatList, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';

export  class LabScreen extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        {this.renderFlatList('red')}
        {this.renderFlatList('green')}
        {this.renderFlatList('purple')}
        {this.renderFlatList('pink')}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

  getRandomData = () => {
    return new Array(100).fill('').map((item, index) => {
      return { title: 'Title ' + (index + 1) };
    });
  };

  renderFlatList(color: string) {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.getRandomData()}
        backgroundColor={color}
        maxHeight={200}
        marginBottom={50}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[snack.expo link](https://snack.expo.io/HyqtjuQz7)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

We can use the built-in [nestedscrollenabled](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled) prop for the children FlatList/ScrollView components.

```
<FlatList nestedScrollEnabled />
```

This is only required for Android (Nested scrolling is supported by default on iOS).

Comment: thanks it helped, added to parent <ScrollViews prop nestedScrollEnabled={true} /> and to children <FlatList nestedScrollEnabled={true} />

Comment: I needed this on iOS for a FlatList inside a ScrollView.

Comment: NOT worked for me.
<ScrollViews prop nestedScrollEnabled={true} />
<FlatList nestedScrollEnabled={true} />
</ScrollViews>

Comment: rnk and @Aniruddha Shevla how is possible that nestedScrollEnabled which is prop of ScrollView ,and used by FlatList

Comment: and what about the reverse case, if we nest scrollview inside a flatlist, this prop doesn't seem to work in that case

Comment: This works perfect for me but still throws the following warning/error: 


VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality

Answer (score 40):

I was having a very similar issue until I came across an almost complete solution in a very helpful comment on one of the GitHub issues for the react-native project: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1966#issuecomment-285130701.

The issue is that the parent component is the only one registering the scroll event. The solution is to contextually decide which component should actually be handling that event based on the location of the press.

You'll need to slightly modify your structure to:

```js
<View>
  <ScrollView>
    <View>
      <FlatList />
    </View>
    <View>
      <FlatList />
    </View>
    <View>
      <FlatList />
    </View>
    <View>
      <FlatList />
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</View>;
```

The only thing I had to change from the GitHub comment was to use `this._myScroll.contentOffset` instead of `this.refs.myList.scrollProperties.offset`.

I've modified your fully working example in a way that allows scrolling of the inner FlatLists.

```js
import { Component, default as React } from "react";
import { View, FlatList, ScrollView, Text } from "react-native";

export default class LabScreen extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { enableScrollViewScroll: true };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() => {
          this.setState({ enableScrollViewScroll: true });
        }}
      >
        <ScrollView
          scrollEnabled={this.state.enableScrollViewScroll}
          ref={(myScroll) => (this._myScroll = myScroll)}
        >
          {this.renderFlatList("red")}
          {this.renderFlatList("green")}
          {this.renderFlatList("purple")}
          {this.renderFlatList("pink")}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }

  getRandomData = () => {
    return new Array(100).fill("").map((item, index) => {
      return { title: "Title " + (index + 1) };
    });
  };

  renderFlatList(color: string) {
    return (
      <View
        onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() => {
          this.setState({ enableScrollViewScroll: false });
          if (
            this._myScroll.contentOffset === 0 &&
            this.state.enableScrollViewScroll === false
          ) {
            this.setState({ enableScrollViewScroll: true });
          }
        }}
      >
        <FlatList
          data={this.getRandomData()}
          backgroundColor={color}
          maxHeight={200}
          marginBottom={50}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hopefully you find this useful!

Comment: Not a problem! I had to solve the same issue myself so I figured I may as well share the solution.

Comment: What are the values that you use for styling on these elements?

Comment: @EricLeFort 2 things: 
1. The second answer is much better
2. in you code:
   " this.setState({ enableScrollViewScroll: false });
              if (this._myScroll.contentOffset === 0
                && this.state.enableScrollViewScroll === false) {"

  setState is async function and there is no guarantee that line after you get a false value on this.state.enableScrollViewScroll in a matter of fact almost sure it won't be having the false value

Comment: this code work well , but when i switch to another view , it doesn't scroll but when i scroll again it scrolls

Comment: Even in 2019, this is the only workaround as far as i know. Tried to use 'nestedscrollenabled' it was not working properly

Comment: I spent the whole day trying to fix drag-and-drop inside a FlatList, while using the react-native-draggable-flatlist library, where it wasn't dragging since the parent ScrollView would start scrolling. Setting scrollEnabled as soon as the dragging movement begins solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

This is the simplest answer that requires zero configuration.. and it works like a charm

```
<ScrollView horizontal={false}>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        <Flatlist
          ....
          ....
        />
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yeaaa, I agree!

Answer (score 16):

I fixed my problem with nested `FlatList` not being able to scroll items on android by simply importing `FlatList`

```js
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

If this would not work, also try to import `ScrollView`.

```js
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
// OR
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

You need to play around with these imports, at least it worked in my case.

Comment: I was importing from `react-native` which caused me invariant violation: withNavigation. Changing to `react-native-gesture-handler` solved!

Comment: It worked perfect thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Try to set the FlatList as nested

nestedScrollEnabled={true}

Comment: It has to be done for all ScrollViews ancestors. Also, the "scroll able" feature on FlatList depend on the height and it is set as:
style ={{   height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 1.5}}

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised that none of the answers actually worked for me. I went searching for the reason ScrollView and FlatList don't work together and found that there are props on FlatList that can accomodate the header and footer areas above and below my FlatList. If I use this I can make sure the whole screen still scrolls and I don't get the error.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/zvflof/comment/j1p2qn3/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) is where I found this answer and I've put an example below.

```
<View>
  <FlatList
    ListHeaderComponent={<View><Text>Top of screen content goes here</Text></View>}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
    data={[{_id: 1, text: 'one'}, {_id: 2, text: 'two'}]
    renderItem={({item}) => (<View><Text>{item.text}</Text></View>)}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: This worked for my use case.  My goal was to have some content above my flatlist but have that content scroll away when trying to view the flatlist.  Nesting a ScrollView and FlatList, at least currently, is giving me lots of problems like firing off way too many refreshes and causing instability

Answer (score 1):

Using View with a flex:1 instead of ScrollView worked for me.

Comment: Did you even read the question? The answer you gave is not possible.

Comment: Doesn't matter what people say. this works perfectly for me after hours of following the other answers.

Comment: Don't even make sense ;(

Answer (score 0):

Use **map** instead of Flatlist, same result and don't break the application

Minha conta

```
   {
      buttonsProfile.map(button => (
         <ArrowButton 
              key={button.key}
              title={button.title}
              iconName={button.icon} 
              toogle={button.toogle}
              onPress={() => {navigation.navigate(button.route)}}
          />
      ))
    }
```

Comment: Is there some sample code you could share?

Comment: see the example below, consider the content as a scroll

Comment: This is only viable for a small list, with a large list it can easily run the app out of memory.

Comment: The map is not a good option and performs less than a react-native core component.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `nestedScrollEnabled` to each flatlist / scrollview but most importantly make sure you do not use pos absolute and allow your screen to flex to be able to scroll

Answer (score -1):

The better answer is to put a horizontal ScrollView inside of the other ScrollView and then the FlatList