# Nested SectionList does not scroll on android

Tags: react-native

I have a SectionList inside of an animated bottom sheet component, but it does not scroll when nested inside of this component on Android. How can I make it behave like on iOS?

the parent Bottom sheet that takes the SectionList as a prop through children:

```
  return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
      <AnimatedView style={animatedStyle}>
        <Line />
        <Title>{title}</Title>
        <>{children}</>
      </AnimatedView>
    </GestureDetector>
  );
```

The SectionList:

```
return (
    <Container>
      <SectionList
        ref={ref => (sectionList.current = ref)}
        ListFooterComponent={renderListFooter}
        sections={sections}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
        renderSectionFooter={renderSectionFooter}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
        scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
        nestedScrollEnabled
        onScrollToIndexFailed={err =>
          console.error('onScrollToIndexFailed ', err)
        }
      />
    </Container>
  );
```

SectionList rendered inside of BottomSheet:

```
return (
    <Wrapper>
      <BottomSheet
        title={t('title.settings', {ns: 'settings'})}
        ref={bottomSheetRef}>
        {renderSettings}
      </BottomSheet>
    </Wrapper>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the SectionList to a FlatList that renders based on the properties instead, and following this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67157649/14631972